# Unable to click a button using Javascript in Chrome to be used in Selenium

Tags: javascript

I am trying to click a button in Selenium for a script but first I'm trying to click the button using JavaScript in the chrome console, however this is proving difficult compared to other sites.

I have tried .click, .trigger ("click") and many more.

Element Source code:

```
<paper-icon-button icon="festify:favorite-border" title="Vote for Eastside (with Halsey &amp; Khalid)" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false"></paper-icon-button>
```

Example of tested JS:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("paper-icon-button").click();
VM1691:1 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...).click is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:52
```

The result of the JavaScript should be the button triggering it's event handler.

Can anyone make any suggestions?

Website in question - https://festify.us/party/-LN2ZKzoRy0eE_BP-R9k - (not my queue for obvious reasons)

Answer (score 1):

As the function says, `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a list of elements, even if that list contains only one element.

If you expect to get only one element, do something like `document.getElementsByTagName(...)[0].click()`. Otherwise, loop over the list and execute `element.click()` on each element.